# In Notepad++, can I copy multiple rows into the leading or trailing space of another file?

Tags: notepad++, copy-paste

Say I have the following 2 files open in Notepad++

[image]

Is it possible to copy the text on the right and paste it into the left, so that I will end up with

> A copy
>
> B this
>
> C text
>
> D over  (etc..)

or

> copy A
>
> this B
>
> text C
>
> over D

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes. Do a block copy/paste.

Hold down <kbd>Alt</kbd> while selecting the text to copy and copy it. Then hold down <kbd>Alt</kbd>  while selecting where you want to copy to in the destination file. Don't select any characters--just drag the cursor down so it flashes on multiple rows. Then paste the text.

Vertical/block editing can also be accomplished by holding <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> along with the arrow keys on your keyboard.

---

Note: This method can also be used to input text on multiple rows simultaneously.
You may also access this via the edit-menu as shown below. *Column Mode* will simply tell you the keyboard shortcut to use. *Column Editor* will insert one or more characters (or numbering) starting at the cursor and in all subsequent lines, until you reach the end of the file.

[image]

Comment: @Snailer It is a *very* handy feature. You're welcome!

Comment: You can also hold `Alt + Shift` with the arrow keys on your keyboard to perform a vertical selection completely via keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, sort of - use column operations.

1. In the copy-from file, hold down the `Alt` key and use the mouse to select a rectangle of text, e.g. the first character of the first four lines. You can go past the end of the line (selecting a block wider than some of the lines)
2. Copy this (e.g. `Ctrl-C`)
3. Flip to your target file
4. Paste it in (e.g. `Ctrl-V`) at the start of the first line
   As you've used a column operation to copy the text, it will insert the same block (without any newlines) into the target file.

Unfortunately it won't handle spaces quite right for your example.  You would need to put a space at the end of the copied block on each line.  Luckily you can use column operations again.

1. After pasting the block in, again hold the `Alt` key, and select a rectangle zero columns wide, to the right of the pasted block. As it's zero-width, notepad++ draws it as a vertical line
2. `Edit > Column Editor` (or press `Alt-C`), and put a `space` in `Text To Insert`.  This will insert a space on each line, to the right of the pasted block

This won't work if the text you paste in is different lengths on each line, though, because you can't select a single vertical line to insert the spaces to.  So I would put a space on the end of each source line before copying - `Ctrl-H` to open the `Replace` dialog, click `Regular Expression` in the bottom right, and replace `$` with `space`.